# How to add a loop cut not along an axis?

Tags: modeling, loop

I'd like to add a loop cut but have it be at an angle. I'm used to houdini, so the best comparison I can make for this is to use a clip node in houdini and just rotate the plane to the angle I want. As far as I can tell in blender you can only add a loop on a specific axis. Is there a way to have it rotated?

Comment: Hi :). *Knife Project* with a simple plane might be what you're looking for. You can rotate the plane to any angle and then "project it" onto geometry to make a loopcut

Comment: Or you can use a the Shear tool on a loop cut.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent in Blender is the *Bisect* tool, which can be activated from the <kbd>T</kbd> toolbar, or simply by <kbd>LMB</kbd> dragging a line across ***selected*** mesh elements.

[image]

Here, the tool has been set to remove the geometry of the backfacing side of the clipping plane. As you can see, there are options, including simply cutting a planar cross-sectional edge-loop. You can rotate the clipping plane about View Z by dragging on the gizmo's circle, or numerically, by setting the plane's normal vector.